# How can I suppress the "No files matching the pattern" message in ESLint?

Tags: continuous-integration, eslint

In my CI setup, I have a test that runs eslint against all JS files. If no JS files exist, it's currently throwing an error. I'd prefer if it'd succeeded when no JS files exist. Is this possible?

```
$ eslint "./src/assets/scripts/**/*.js"

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 5.7.0.
No files matching the pattern "./src/assets/scripts/**/*.js" were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.

ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: How about only calling eslint if said files exist?

Comment: I suppose I could write something for that, I hadn't thought of it that way.

Comment: ESLint: 6.8.0  but error persists.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The `--no-error-on-unmatched-pattern` flag was added in `v6.8.0` of ESLint.

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#no-error-on-unmatched-pattern

Comment: That is just hiding of an error when unmatched pattern happens. I kindly suggest my solution bellow.

Answer (score 157):

What worked for me was `changing single quotes to escaped double quotes`

So from:

```
"lint": "eslint '**/*.{ts,tsx}'"
```

To:

```
"lint": "eslint \"**/*.{ts,tsx}\""
```

The reason is because it depends on the console you are using - possibly the operation system (that's why it can work for you while it's not working for others and via versa) Source: https://dev.to/gruckion/comment/b65c

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks. @Sebastian Voráč

Comment: This worked for me in windows

Comment: This is cool but has nothing to do with the question

Comment: @MichaelPearson this literally fixing the error described in the question (unlike hiding the error as it's in accepted answer)

Comment: Thank you very much for this lint script example! In my case, --ext flag from doc didn't work for me properly... So I could not use `eslint ./** .js,.ts,.jsx,.tsx`, it worked incorrectly somehow :)

Comment: While this answer addresses shell differences which may also cause the same error message, it is not a solution to "If no JS files exist, it's currently throwing an error. I'd prefer if it'd succeeded when no JS files exist.", which the OP is asking for.

Comment: i was using windows it it was happening to me. resolved thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Was able to dig up [this closed issue on ESLint's GitHub](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/10587). Sounds like this is a common problem, and has no good workaround, other than manually checking for the files existence before attempting to lint, as suggested by @user2864740

Answer (score 5):

I have the same error

> No files matching the pattern **".ts,"** were found

I just removed spaces between types `.js, .ts, .tsx` in config and it works.

From:

```
"lint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --ext .js, .ts, .tsx .",
```

To

```
 "lint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --ext .js,.ts,.tsx .",
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had to change from

```
"lint": "eslint \"**/*.{ts, tsx}\""
```

to

```
"lint": "eslint \"**/*.{ts,tsx}\""
```

which is literally a space between `ts` & `tsx` / `js` & `jsx`

Comment: Thanks! It was the space after comma for me too!

Comment: It's just my answers copy.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add this command to your package.json file
"scripts": {
"eslint": "eslint"
}

Step 2: Run below command to clear cache
npm run eslint -- --clearCache